# How to solve error:git cloning error?

Tags: git, git-clone, brunch

I am trying to create a new branch in command prompt but I get the below error:

[image]

If any one can help me out. I will be very grateful.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Create new branch?

Comment: yes,  I am setting up a project for angularjs and I already installed 'bower dependencies' and 'npm' and all. If I do "npm install brunch -g" then give command "brunch new" I am getting 'this deirectory is already an npm project '.

Comment: Check if you have binary git folder in your path. commands like `git init` should works everywhere in the console. If not fix this

Comment: not branch, i am trying to create 'brunch new'@CommercialSuicide

Answer (score 0):

To create new branch you just need to type `git checkout -b [name-of-new-branch]`.
It will create new branch and automatically checkout.

Comment: git is not recognised as an internal or external command @Comercial Suicide

Comment: @new_comer Do you use windows? And did you do `git init`?

Comment: yes i use windows and i dont do git init. @Comerical Suicide

Comment: I advise to look through the complex lessons for understanding git, it's hard to explain all the aspects. At first you need install git and then make `git init` from your repo. Then you need to tie your local repo with remote repo. Only after it you can start using git. And When you installed git, make sure you select the _'run Git from the Windows command prompt'_ option. http://git-scm.com/download.

Answer (score 0):

can you provide a better error msg?
with the limited info you've provided it could be a connection or local permissions error.
Have you tried cloning it to a different folder?

Comment: No, i didnt try to clone other folders @Stickman . What more can I give you. Just tell me

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Git installed on Windows? If not install it and when installing it select to add git path in $PATH during installation. If yes, ensure that you have git in your $path so you can use it everywhere in your console.